# Can you make git apply with a dry run?

Tags: git, patch, git-apply

I would like to know, which files would be written when applying a .patch file with git apply.

Is there a way to apply a .patch file in git with a dry run?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
git apply --summary path/to/file.patch
```

would output info *without* applying the patch.

See in the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply#Documentation/git-apply.txt---summary).

Comment: I have created a patch file in one branch. I want to apply this patch to another branch. Before applying, i wanted to see which patches are going to be applied and which not. Using the command given by you, I am not seeing any output. Patch is also not not applied. Nothing  is happening.

Comment: Did you try the above command from a branch where the patch doesn't exist? Yes it's bound to fail. Try to retrieve it from the other branch with `git apply --summary <otherbranch>:path/to/file.patch` (Mind the `:` inbetween the branch name and the file path.)

Comment: but patch is not going to exist in the branch where i want to apply it, right? That's why I am "applying" it to the destination branch, right? 
I wanted to transfer the changes done by me in one branch to another branch. So i created patch file from the diff in source branch. Now , I am going to apply this diff patch to another branch.

Comment: Right, the patch isn't present as a file in your current working tree. That's the point of the `<refspec>:<path>` syntax I suggested above. It tells git to retrieve the content of your patch where it is stored. Here, look at the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/revisions#Documentation/revisions.txt-emltrevgtltpathgtemegemHEADREADMEememmasterREADMEem).